# Magento2: Add product to parent and child categories on import

Tags: category, magento-2.2.5, product-import

I am trying to import products in Magento2.2.5 Products have many categories :
e.g
Default Category/A1/A2/A3, Default Category/B1/B2/B3

When i check the product configuration, the product only has A3 and B3 checked as categories when it should have all the following categories checked for the product:

Default Category
Default Category/A1
Default Category/A1/A2
Default Category/A1/A2/A3

Default Category/B1
Default Category/B1/B2
Default Category/B1/B2/B3

Let me know the solution for adding parent categories checked on child categories

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your csv  check column categories

you have just added **Default Category/A1/A2/A3** instead of

**Default Category/A1, Default Category/A1/A2 ,Default Category/A1/A2/A3**

If you want to get better idea please check in vanila magento:

export only any simple product parent category Gear and child category is Bags.

you can got the solution of your problem.